# command not found when using makefile to run batch file on Windows 10

Tags: python, makefile, cygwin

When I try to run a makefile (type "make test" in terminal) which runs a batch file I get the equivalent error:

```
cd directory_path && test.bat
/bin/sh: test.bat: command not found
make: *** [makefile:58: test] Error 127
```

The makefile is:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    cd directory_path && test.bat
    python path/test.py
```

(I changed names of the batch file, the directory path, etc. to try and make things more generic)

I can manually type "cd directory_path" and then "test.bat" and those both work. This makefile works on other systems. It only doesn't work on mine. I think it is an issue with how I installed Cygwin and how I run "make.exe".

I can use make to compile C code, but I also get an error trying to use make to run python scripts. The makefile from before also has a command for python path/test.py. This also isn't working on my system. If I delete the batch file line, but keep the python command it throws the error:

```
python path/test.py
make: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile:59: test] Error 127.
```

I don't understand why it throws the error of no such file or directory since the path leads to the file, and if i put the python script in the same working directory as the makefile then it still can't find it.

Any ideas/solutions on these problems? Thank you!

EDIT:

Doug Henderson:
I started a cmd prompt at the place with the make file and entered all of these commands in

```
uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 james-mobl2 3.1.6(0.340/5/3) 2020-07-09 08:20 x86_64 Cygwin

which make
/usr/bin/make

make -v
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

which python
which: no python in
(/cygdrive/c/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-8.0.252.09-hotspot/bin:
/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:
/cygdrive/c/windows:
/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:
/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
/cygdrive/c/Users/james/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PuTTY:
/usr/bin:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-8.0.252.09 hotspot/bin:
/cygdrive/c/Users/james/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps)
```

(I cleaned up the output a little to make it more legible). This and which test.bat are the only commands that failed.

```
python -V
Python 3.8.5
```

The change directory changed correctly

```
which test.bat
which: no test.bat in 
(/cygdrive/c/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-8.0.252.09-hotspot/bin:
/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:
/cygdrive/c/windows:
/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:
/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
/cygdrive/c/Users/james/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PuTTY:
/usr/bin:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-8.0.252.09 hotspot/bin:
/cygdrive/c/Users/james/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps)
```

I added `cmd /c test.bat` to the makefile and it worked, but I've also had the batch file run on different systems without that addition. I also have a lot batch files in the actual makefile so this solution works but isn't ideal. It also didn't fix the python script not running.

I didn't initially have cmd.exe in my path, but I added it before entering those commands.

I'm not sure what you mean by starting my PATH in bash with `/usr/bin;/bin;THE_REST`

MadScientist:
I was manually entering it into a Windows Terminal. Is it possible to have Cygwin invoke a Windows command.com shell?

What I did was go to directory that contained the makefile. Open a windows terminal by typing 'cmd' in the address bar. I would then type 'make test'. That obviously led to the issues. I then went through and manually entered the commands I thought the makefile was supposed to invoke. So I entered 'cd directory_path && test.bat'. This ran.

Matzeri:
I don't really know. I'm completely new to POSIX, etc. I'm guessing I'm using Windows style, and judging from other responses, I'm trying to use Cygwin to do a non-POSIX style.

Thank you, everyone for responses!

Comment: Please show us the results of all the following commands: `uname -a`, `which make`, `make -v`, `which python`, `python -V`, `cd directory_path ; which test.bat`. Also, you must use `cmd /c test.bat` to run a batch script from a makefile. (Use `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe` if cmd.exe is not in path.) I suggest your PATH in bash start with `/usr/bin;/bin;THE_REST`. Unless absolutely necessary, THE_REST should contain no folders! By default it contains all your windows path folders, most, if not all, of which are unnecessary in cygwin. (Note test is a linux command.)

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing Posix and not Posix stuff ? `test.bat` is Windows style (not Posix) and Cygwin is Posix so whould use something like `test.sh`

Comment: When you say _I can manually type_ are you typing that into a **Cygwin shell** or are you typing it into a **Windows terminal** (command.com)?  If the former it won't work, the same as it won't work from make.  The latter will work, but Cygwin make is not invoking a Windows command.com shell it's invoking a POSIX / cygwin shell.

Comment: @matzeri Thank you for your response. I updated my question to cover what you suggested.

Comment: @DougHenderson Thank you for your response. I updated my question to cover what you suggested.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you for your response. I updated my question to cover what you suggested.

Comment: I'm afraid that to work in Windows you'll just have to get used to this confusion.  In POSIX systems a script contains inside itself (as its first line) what interpreter it should use: shell, python, perl, whatever, so you can run it regardless of what shell you're using.  In Windows you have to run the right interpreter yourself.  Whatever interpreter you are currently running is what's used by default so if the script uses a different interpreter you have to run that.

Comment: If you're currently in a cygwin shell (POSIX sh) and you want to run a `.bat` script (cmd.com) you have to run *cmd /c foo.bat*.  If you're already in a cmd.com shell you can just run `foo.bat` directly, but if you want to run a POSIX script you have to run `sh foo.sh`.  GNU make will run commands in whichever shell it finds, or else in a specific one always, depending on how it's built or what you've set in your makefile in the `SHELL` variable.

Comment: @MadScientist Oh ok. I'm assuming that my GNU was set up to find the cygwin shell. Hence why the makefile runs the batch script when I enter cmd /c, but doesn't require that on other systems. If I understand what you're saying, I would just need to make it so GNU finds the cmd.com shell? To do this do I need to uninstall Cygwin and reinstall it, while clicking some special setup? Is there a way to toggle this setting?

I could set the SHELL variable in my makefile, but I'm trying to not have to modify the makefile at all to get this working (for consistency with other users purposes).

Comment: I don't know the answer to that: I don't really use Windows very much and I don't ever use cygwin.  Also, my understanding is that the cygwin environment builds their own GNU make version with specific settings and perhaps even patches: you'll have to check with them.  However, I would doubt that there is any such cygwin option.  On other systems you might have run a version of GNU make that was _NOT_ compiled as part of cygwin: it might have been built with MinGW or VisualStudio as a native application.  Then it might work differently.

Comment: @MadScientist Oh ok. I'll keep looking. Thank you so much for taking your time to help out!!

Comment: The thing is that `&&` _itself_ is a POSIX shell operation.  That's not how you combine commands in Windows batch files.  So, that command line must _always_ be run by a POSIX shell or it will simply not work.  I'm not sure why it works for some people.  Maybe the cygwin POSIX shell "knows" how to run `.bat` files normally, then I don't know why it doesn't work for you.  But, changing `SHELL` to `cmd.com` in that makefile will definitely not work.

Comment: @MadScientist I don't understand either. I can type 'cd directory_path && foo.bat' into windows cmd.exe and the batch file in directory_path works

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure cygwin is installed with basic packages --> Some basic packages not installed with cygwin try below link to install some basic package, uninstall the cygwin and install it again with following basic package :
   https://wiki.usask.ca/display/MESH/Running+Python+from+the+Cygwin+Terminal#RunningPythonfromtheCygwinTerminal-Cygwin
2. make sure cygwin's bin folder is added to your environment variable (e.g., C:\cygwin64\bin)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

If `cmd /c test.bat` works then `.` is probably not in your PATH.  Always do `./test.bat` when you want to run something in the current directory.  Never count on the PATH unless you have set it yourself.  Also make sure the file is executable.  `chmod +x test.bat`